# extracting date format from getdate()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am trying to get the getdate in the YYYYMMDDHHMM format.

I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) AS VARCHAR)+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())) 
+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(minute,GETDATE()))
```

It's giving me correct output but is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: No, this is pretty much it until [next release](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/08/sql-server-denali-format-most-wanted.html). Unless you want to use style 121 and 2 REPLACE calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know how much "simpler" this is, but:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
       + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this (since it references GETDATE() only once, they could never evaluate to inconsistent values from different days):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(16),GETDATE(),120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')
```

Comment: @MartinSmith It's my understanding that GETDATE() is only evaluated once per column in a query. Am I wrong on that point?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Not sure. I was of the opinion that it would be once per function reference. Will have to do a quick test!

Comment: @Joe [This test indicates once per function reference](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115712/) (BTW: Stack Exchange cache query results which is why it will always say it took 2706 iterations)